# name.vue.twig file, is it possible?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, symfony-1.4, webpack-encore

I'm not very experimented with symfony and I work with vue.js. I've seen there are nice ways to use both at the same time (webpack encore...), but I couldn't find anyone talking about this :

When working with a webpack template inside a symfony app, can I make .vue.twig files like I'd make .html.twig files ?

Comment: Are you using symfony1? Twig normally implies symfony2+.

Comment: I'm working on symfony 4 right now (was on 3 at the time of the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for forgetting this post. So here is the answer :

The best solution I found was to install webpack encore (very well documented in symfony's doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)).
Then you just need one .twig file in wich you'll load your .js and .css files that get built by webpack encore.

Answer (score 0):

You probably *can* figure out a way to use PHP rendering for your Vue templates, but I wouldn't recommend it. Especially if you're using an old framework like symfony1, moving towards modern, unencumbered, static Vue components can provide a path out of old-framework-lock-in.